# How to show bytesRead on Progressbar ?

Tags: android, progress-bar

I created a class that shows progress.
**like this**

My question is How can i show this values on progressbar ?

```
 Log.i(TAG, String.format("Upload - %s : %d / %d (%%%d) %s", realPath, bytesRead, totalBytes, percentage, completed ? "completed" : "ongoing"));
```